# Materialize - Custom css has no effect

Tags: html, css, materialize

I would like to style the sidebar of my application but somehow the css file is ignored or something.

Code SideBar:

```
<!-- SideNavBar -->
    <div class="sidenavbar">
        <ul id="sidenav" class="sidenav sidenav-fixed logged-in"
            style="display: none; width: 250px;">
            <li class="logged-in" style="display: none;">
                <a href="#" class="grey-text" id="logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
            <li class="admin" style="display: none;">
                <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-create">Create Guide</a>
            </li>
            <li class="admin" style="display: none;">
                <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-signup">Create new Account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="admin" style="display: none;">
                <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-addadmin">Add Admin</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.sidenavbar{
    background-color: black;
}
.sidenavbar ul li :hover{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe since the unordered list and the list items have a display of "none" the div of class "sidenavbar" has no width or height. This is why you cannot see the black background.

Comment: It has a display of none at the beginning but I change that when the user is signed in. Even then I can't see a color change.

Answer (score 0):

you should use your custom css file after source css file. e.x:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" src="yourcssfilename.css">
```

Comment: I added that, but I didn't include it in the code provided, sorry. should have mentioned that